# Repository removal fails

Tags: apt, libreoffice, ppa

I followed the directions at:

https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppa-on-ubuntu-linux/

to attempt to remove the ppa: "libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list". Pasted below is that attempt, and it failed. Why does that command not work to remove that PPA? Why cannot the command find that PPA which is clearly in "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/" ?

```
stephen@stephen:~$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
balena-etcher.list
ddebs.list
diesch-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
gezakovacs-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-jammy.list
kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-jammy.list.save
libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ubuntu-firefox-aurora-jammy.list.save
ubuntustudio-ppa-ubuntu-backports-jammy.list
ubuntustudio-ppa-ubuntu-backports-jammy.list.save
virtualbox.list
stephen@stephen:~$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:stephen/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
[sudo] password for stephen: 
ERROR: ppa 'stephen/libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list' not found (use --login if private)
```

Comment: just do 'sudo add-apt-repository --remove libreoffice-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list'. The source says to "replace ppa:username/ppa-name with the details of the ppa you actually want to remove" and gives an example below. don't use *your* username, the username is part of the ppa details

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the exact name of the PPA to be removed, that is the one you used to add it and not the name of the `.list` file.
As described in the link you posted, the format is `ppa:<username>/<ppa-name>`; however, the username is not *your* username, but the one of the user who owns the PPA on Launchpad (in your case, `libreoffice`).

If you don't know the PPA name, you can find it by running `apt update` and looking in the output for the source/PPA you want to remove. The format will be:

```
Get:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/<username>/<ppa-name>/ubuntu jammy InRelease
```

In your specific case, it will be

```
Get:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
```

Therefore, the name you need is `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` and the command will be

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

[Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-list-and-remove-ppa-repository-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux) you can find further info on PPA management in Ubuntu.